# What version label to use for a forked maven project?

Tags: maven, versioning

I often times have to fork a Java project that uses Maven (usually on github).

When I fork the project and make my changes I generally want to cut a release to my own private (but on the internet) maven repository.

Thus the question of what the version label should be for my custom release. I can't do `SNAPSHOT` as I need it to be a release. Sometimes I suffix the project with `.ADAMGENT` (cause I'm a narcissist). Lets say I fork `1.0.4-SNAPSHOT`. I might change it to `1.0.4.ADAMGENT` . I have no idea if that is a good idea. In some cases I can't even suffix it with `.ADAMGENT` as Spring's Gradle build tools don't like that. So for Spring projects I do `.ADAMGENT.RELEASE` or `.ADAMGENT.M1` if its a milestone.

**What do others do?**

**Update:** *although I said fork I ment more of a patch level change. The bounty (by a different user) on the other hand might be for fork and/or patch*

Comment: @bmargulies I can't do SNAPSHOT because I need to do a release for a project that depends on the fork (I use the release plugin).

Comment: If you do a release of the above you will get *1.0-adam* ...that's a release.

Comment: @khmarbaise most of the builds I encounter don't have the release plugin setup correctly so I have to change the version number manually. I supposed I should checkin to git the snapshot though.

Comment: @AdamGent If you work that way i wouldn't checkin the SNAPSHOT. I would checkin *1.0-adam* instead which makes clear this is a special version which belong to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually add a suffix (e.g. name) and then a running number to avoid confusing multiple releases that I make based on the upstream version. In your setup, this would probably translate to the something like this:

```
1.0.4-ADAMGENT-1
```

which would then be followed by `1.0.4-ADAMGENT-2` in case you have to make another change.

Definitely keep the `artifact` and `group` ID from the original project and also the version you're basing your changes on, this will come in handy later, if you ever have to find out which version you've been working on. And it makes switching to the official version easier, if your changes are included upstream.

Comment: If you decide to use the version qualifier, you should be sure to understand how Maven evaluates qualifiers. You can see it on the [ComparableVersion](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=blob;f=maven-artifact/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion.java) class.

Comment: This will upset OSGi versioning unfortunately, it seems to be very opinionated about using semver.

Answer (score 22):

Because you are forking, use a different group ID.

The reality is, that once you start making changes to your local fork, it *is* a different artifact.  An artifact that is made by your organization, not the one you took it from.

With regard to version number, if your changes are always going to be minor, I'd use the major and possibly the minor version number of the source tree when I forked, otherwise, I'd start all over again at 1.0.0 and make a note in the project POM regarding what version I forked it from.

For example:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.adamgent</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-xyz</artifactId> <!-- same artifact ID -->
    <version>1.0.0-RELEASE</version>
    <name>My Project XYZ</name> <!-- different display name -->
    <description>My fork of project XYZ created from v5.42.0 of original sources.</description>
    ....
```

It isn't any more difficult to switch a group ID for a dependency than to switch a version ID.  Both mechanisms can be used to easily get you the release artifact you want.  However, by changing the group ID, you get the follow advantages:

1. you can more easily keep track of your forks within Nexus
2. you eliminate any confusion that might arise from having artifacts from an organization that they did not create
3. you stay within the [standard guidelines](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html) for Maven version identifiers

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you will have to exclude any transitive dependencies on the original jar or do the scope=provided hack: `<scope>provided</scope>`. Thus it actually is quite a bit more difficult to change the group id or else you will get accidental duplicate class issues.

Comment: To make it easier, you can add your exclusion to the `dependencyManagement` section of the parent POM -- the same place you have to add your new version. Personally, I prefer the minor hassle of explicitly managing exclusions (noisy errors if done wrong) to the potential for confusing other developers, especially new ones.

Comment: For some reason I have had issues w/ exclusions even in the parent pom. I try to do it often but sometimes it seems I end up having to put exclusions in almost every dependency so I just give up and do the `provided` hack. I believe commons logging is an example of this. No matter how many times I try to exclude it I have to do `provided` to make it go away. That being said I don't really agree with you that the artifact name should change anyway. Its not a fork IMHO because its in the same namespace (the package/class names stay the same). A reasonable fork would change the namespace.

Comment: If you use the same groupId as the original project, you would not be permitted to deploy your forked project to Maven Central. That is why your projects need to have a domain that you control.

Comment: I hear you on the `provided` tactic, I've done it myself and don't love it either.  At least it works reliably well.  On the other point, I think the artifact name (and possibly the version number) should stay the same and just the group Id change.

Comment: @DavidV I would not deploy it to maven central but to a github/googlecode semi-public repo. I guess I said **fork** but I really meant **patched** a few changes because the project is moving too slow.

Comment: @AdamGent The Maven documents say the groupId identifies the project uniquely across all other projects. I suggested the problem with Maven Central to note that you should follow the same Maven convention.

Comment: @AdamGent Also, any change-even a patch-is a fork that has diverged from the original project. Unless you are saying that you want to build the current project while the owners are not yet ready to build it.

Comment: @DavidV yes I often mean I want to build the current project and there is no release but not always. Imagine the library is something that is used all over the place by transitive dependencies (ie spring lib or apache commons) and the bug in this library is rather critical. By your approach I would have to exclude or do the provided hack and basically lie and say this is a different jar because of the groupid change but its really the same java (namespace). Your approach might work for an OSGI environment but so would just changing the version number.

Comment: @DavidV also Sonatype.. the gods of Maven these days apparently even suffix versions: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonatype.nexus.nexus/1.1.1/1.1.1.rip and http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.ldap/nexus-ldap-realm-plugin

Comment: @AdamGent As I understood the original question, I think HDave's answer was correct and he had linked to the Maven guidelines on the matter. As I now understand it, you are going to build straight from the original repository. So it is not a fork. Perhaps we can call it a premature build. In this case, I think that changing the version is ok, but I don't have any documentation to point you to stating that.

Comment: @AdamGent If you use a version number though, you might want to take a look at [ComparableVersion](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=blob;f=maven-artifact/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion.java) and see if you can make something like `-beta-adamgent-1`. Simply using `-adamgent-1` will be a later version than `-rc` or `-ga`.

Comment: Also, those "suffixes" are called qualifiers in Maven.

Comment: Unfortunately OSGi seems to be even more opinionated than Maven and gets quite upset about version suffixes etc. I haven't found anything sane that's OSGi-friendly and lets me still track "this is patch 4 on top of upstream 1.14.5"

Answer (score 2):

If it's a snapshot, I suggest to use the original revision number (is that possible with git?) or the date you forked it, with your ADAMGENT (adding your own suffix is a very good idea)

e.g.

```
1.0.4-2011-09-12.ADAMGENT
```

Comment: The date is a good idea because occasionally I foobar the release and need to add more stuff which causes a maven cache cleanup nightmare (have to log on to the build machine and cleanup ~/.m2).

Comment: That sounds like an awkward way around the golden rule: don't make two releases that are essentially the same. If you need to re-release, just increment the minor version number. If there's a cosmetic reason not to do that (in which case I don't think the date is helping you much either) perhaps just add another dot-digit (`.1`) to the version number.

Answer (score 1):

I did come up with my own solution. I won't mark it correct as I think @DavidH does have some valid points and if Maven had the level of configuration that Ivy has of replacing groupid (and/or I figured out in sonatype how to do it) I probably would mark it correct. Otherwise I firmly believe a fork should be a different namespace and Java package names should be somewhat inline with your projects groupid. Also for my situation I often need to do this for a bug fix so its not a fork.

This is what I do and it is based on how maven reads version numbers and what Sonatype somewhat does:

First I setup my own public but non central repository where I will publish my version into. You can use github and/or googlecode to host such a repo. There are guides on the net on how to do this and how to publish to it so I won't go into that.

For version numbers I follow this format except for Spring because Spring's build system has strange requirements as noted in my question:

`1.0.4-ADAMGENT-1`

Some more changes and release:

`1.0.4-ADAMGENT-2`

You can see that Maven will mostly understand this format by [looking at the code](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-artifact/xref/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/DefaultArtifactVersion.html). The issue is the `ADAMGENT` qualifier. Maven only understand a few qualifiers ["alpha", "beta", "milestone", "rc", "snapshot", "", "sp"` and "ga", "final", "cr"](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-artifact/xref/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion.html#150) properly.

The ones it does not are lexical ordered (`ADAMGENT` in this case) which is fine and I suppose you could up the incremental version (`4`) if that is a problem.

Comment: This is basically what Pascal Thivent recommended in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2619313/14379. It does make sense for patches, but if they become large enough to be considered a fork (or never make it to the upstream project) a new groupId is probably the way to go. (Lower-case qualifiers are probably more common than upper-case though.)