# How to properly fork a maven project?

Tags: maven

I'm trying to fork a discontinued maven library that is already in the main repository.

What are good guidelines to follow when doing so?

Should the groupId/artifactId be changed so that it doesn't clash with the library that's already in the maven repository?

This library will be a dependency to a project that will also be available publicly(in the maven repo) so this library should also be there.

The modifications add improvements and some changes on how the library works, so I would like it to be separate from the old versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What version label to use for a forked maven project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415550/what-version-label-to-use-for-a-forked-maven-project)

Answer (score 8):

Sonatype [recommends](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/choosing-your-coordinates.html) you change the `groupId` when you fork a project.

> B2) upload them under your the forked project
>   groupId (presumably one you own and appropriate for the fork)

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are forking the other project for internal use? Then I would keep the original groupId/artifactId but add a postfix to the version. If the upstream version is 1.0.0 your custom version would be 1.0.0-custom.

If you create a public fork then you basically have to use a new project name and so a new groupId/artifactId.

Comment: I would suggest to go the same way with a special version string.

Comment: No, the project will be posted to the main maven repository. I don't know, but I'd guess if I don't change the groupId, the new library will clash with the old one. Perhaps I should also add a postfix to the artifactId.

Comment: It's better to use `1.0.0.custom` than `1.0.0-custom` since otherwise Maven can get mixed up with classifiers.

Comment: @artbristol That's an interesting point but I think using a classifier is actually a better approach. Here's the official [docu](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html). The version format should be in the format x.y.z-classifier to make sure they are compared properly. This also matches the format of [semver](http://semver.org/) if that's a concern. But if you know of any concrete problems I'd love to know.

Comment: I've had problems uploading custom versions to Nexus, where it autodetected the classifier and stripped it from the version. You can work around it obviously.